Azure B2C presignup API Connector failing to reach API with sign in/signup user flow
I have an Azure B2C API connector assigned to "Before creating the user", as part of my sign in/sign up flow.
This points to my API, and does pre-processing before a user signs up.


I noticed when a user signs up now via local account, this flow is failing.
The logs produced this error:
{"errorMessage":"There was a problem processing your request. Please try again.","numberOfAttempts":2}


Logs within my own API do not show any requests to the endpoint URL specified in the connector, so this failure is happening before reaching my API.
I've tried the following:

Double checked that the URL the connector is referencing is correct and working.
Attempted to re-create the flow.
Tried creating a user on another browser/clearing cookies.
Manually calling the API via postman works fine and I am able to access it.

To clarify, this was working a few months ago and I have not made any code changes since then.
Disabling the API connector resolves the issue, so I believe there is no other issues with my user flow.
I noticed the same problem being described here, with no resolution.
Any and all help is appreciated.

Refer this MsArticle
